# Why method contextInitialized doesn't invoke?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, listener

I wrote following java classes:

```
@Configuration
public class UiConfig {


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public AppListener getAppListener(){
        AppListener appListener = new AppListener();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" appListener method ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        return appListener;
    }
    @Bean
    public MyListener getMyListener(){
        MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" myListener method ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        return myListener;
    }
}
class MyListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" hello ContextLoaderListener ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" hello AppListener");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

I  run my tomcat an see next log:

```
21.10.2013 18:56:18 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in

...

org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,messageSource,getAppListener,getMyListener]; root of factory hierarchy


 appListener method 




 myListener method 




 hello AppListener


INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4424 ms
21.10.2013 18:56:34 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'

...

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/updateVacancy],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.updateVacancyPRG(org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,java.lang.Integer)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/addVacancy],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.VacancyMenuController.addVacancy(com.epam.hhsystem.model.vacancy.Vacancy,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'


 appListener method 




 myListener method 




 hello AppListener




 hello AppListener


INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 926 ms
21.10.2013 18:56:34 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 18:56:34 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
21.10.2013 18:56:34 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15692 ms
INFO : com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider - User with name 'Nikolay_tkachev' log in
/index
21.10.2013 19:01:01 org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Oct 21 18:56:34 MSK 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5dd22889: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,baseMenuController,candidateMenuController,provider,eventMenuController,homeController,uiConfig,vacancyMenuController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,messageSource,getAppListener,getMyListener]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@19a072a6
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Oct 21 18:56:29 MSK 2013]; root of context hierarchy

....

21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
21.10.2013 19:01:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I don't understand why I don't see string `" hello ContextLoaderListener "` at this log?
Can you explain me it?

**P.S.**

in web.xml I have this entry

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why method contextInitialized doesn't invoke?

Your class

```
class MyListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" hello ContextLoaderListener ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

is a `ServletContextListener` that hasn't been registered with the `Servlet` container which is responsible for calling `contextInitialized`. Because of this, that method is never called.

A `ServletContextListener` would typically be registered in the container's `web.xml` with a `<listener>` entry.

Comment: How I can bind this listener to dispatcher servlet ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow You don't bind it to the `DispatcherServlet`, you register it with the `Servlet` container. Consider checking out Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` interface.

Comment: I have *<listener> entry* in web.xml

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sure, so the container will register an instance of `ContextLoaderListener`, but that won't be the instance you created in your `@Configuration` class. If you want to dynamically register listeners, for example, from a Spring application context, you will need to use a `ServletContainerInitializer` or Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Comment: What conditions are required for using ServletContainerInitializer ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow It's all explained in the javadoc. But honestly, use `WebApplicationInitializer`, which is as simple as making a class that `implements` it.